# discord.py more than one command word

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import music
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import urllib.parse, urllib.request, re
from urllib import parse, request
import re

playcmd = ["play", "p"]

class music(commands.Cog):
def **init**(self, client):
self.client = client

```
    @client.command()
    async def join(ctx):
        if (ctx.author.voice):
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.send("First join voice channel")

    @client.command()
    async def leave(ctx):
        if (ctx.voice_client):
            await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
            await ctx.send("Ok")
     
    @client.command()
    async def {playcmd}(ctx, *, search):

        if(ctx.voice_client):
            print("already on voice channel")
          
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()

        query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
        html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
        search_content= html_content.read().decode()
        search_results = re.findall(r'\/watch\?v=\w+', search_content)
        #print(search_results)
        await ctx.send('Now playing: ''https://www.youtube.com' + search_results[0])

        url = 'https://www.youtube.com' + search_results[0]

        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @client.command()
    async def pause(ctx):
       await ctx.send("paused")
       await ctx.voice_client.pause()

    @client.command()
    async def resume(ctx):
        await ctx.send("resumed")
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()

    @client.command()
    async def youtube(ctx, *, search):
      query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
      html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
      search_content= html_content.read().decode()
      search_results = re.findall(r'\/watch\?v=\w+', search_content)
      #print(search_results)
      await ctx.send('https://www.youtube.com' + search_results[0])
```

def setup(client):
client.add_cog(music(client))

can someone make this working?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `playcmd = ["play", "p"]` I assume you want your command to work with both play and p. In that case you can use the aliases keyword argument in your decorator.
So instead of

```py
playcmd = ["play", "p"]
@client.command()
async def {playcmd}(ctx, *, search):
    ...
```

use

```py
@client.command(aliases=["p"])
async def play(ctx, *, search):
    ...
```

Here we aren't specifying play as an alias since it's already the command name

however there is something else that bothers me, you seem to not have self in any of your functions, is it really in a cog (therefore in a class)? if it is not then `def setup(client): client.add_cog(music(client))` does not make sense